# Stuck in Observable Loop with MdSnackBar in Angular Material for Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material2, angular2-observables

I want to show a snackbar when my login fails that says 'error connecting'. That much is simple. But then I would like it to try again either after 10 seconds when it is dismissed or after the action dismisses the snackbar. But my observable runs immediately and I am stuck in an infinite observable loop trying to login immediately after it has failed.

`login.page.ts`

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { UserService, HelpersService, AuthService } from '../../services/';

@Component({
  selector: 'login-page',
  templateUrl: './login.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.page.scss']
})
export class LoginPage {
  loginError: any;
  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private auth: AuthService,
    public helpers: HelpersService,
  ) { }

  login() {
    this.auth.login().then((response) => {
      this.router.navigate(['/']);
    }).catch(error => {
      this.loginError = this.helpers.notify('error connecting', 'try again', 10000);
      this.helpers.notifyAction(this.loginError, this.login());
    });
  };


}
```

`helpers.service.ts`

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { MdSnackBar, MdSnackBarRef } from '@angular/material';

@Injectable()
export class HelpersService {

  constructor(public snackBar: MdSnackBar) {}

  notify(message: string, action: string, duration: number) {
    return this.snackBar.open(message, action, {duration});
  }

  notifyAction(notification: MdSnackBarRef<any>, next) {
    return notification.onAction().subscribe(() => next);
  }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Live Example Infinity Login](https://plnkr.co/edit/Ndc6z7zK82ffrcDauyqU?p=preview)**

You need to pass function instead of calling it. And also take care about context by using arrow function or `bind`.

**login.page.ts**

```
this.helpers.notifyAction(this.loginError, () => this.login());
```

**helpers.service.ts**

```
notifyAction(notification: MdSnackBarRef<any>, next) {
  notification.afterDismissed().subscribe(next);

  return notification.onAction().subscribe(notification.dismiss);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You were almost there. Please pay attention to my comments in your sources.

login.page.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { UserService, HelpersService, AuthService } from '../../services/';

@Component({
  selector: 'login-page',
  templateUrl: './login.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.page.scss']
})
export class LoginPage {
  loginError: any;
  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private auth: AuthService,
    public helpers: HelpersService,
  ) { }

  login() {
    this.auth.login().then((response) => {
      this.router.navigate(['/']);
    }).catch(error => {
      this.loginError = this.helpers.notify('error connecting', 'try again', 10000);
      this.helpers.notifyAction(this.loginError, this.login); // no parenthesis here!
    });
  };

}
```

helpers.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { MdSnackBar, MdSnackBarRef } from '@angular/material';

@Injectable()
export class HelpersService {

  constructor(public snackBar: MdSnackBar) {}

  notify(message: string, action: string, duration: number) {
    return this.snackBar.open(message, action, {duration});
  }

  notifyAction(notification: MdSnackBarRef<any>, next) {
    return notification.onAction().subscribe(() => next()); // they are here!
  }

}
```